# "do not show message again" checkbox in Tkinter warning message

Tags: python, checkbox, tkinter, message

I'm creating message boxes in Tkinter using `tkMessageBox.showwarning`.

Does Tkinter let you insert a sort of checkbox with the message that says, for example, "do not show again" so when selected the message won't appear the next time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the standard dialogs don't support that.

If you want such a feature you'll have to build your own dialog out of a `Toplevel` window and other widgets.